# website security sql database access password php

Tags: php, sql

I am a beginner in PHP and SQL. Maybe this is a silly question, but I really want to hear from the professionals since I am planning on getting into website industry too.

When we try to do an sql query on the website, through PHP for example, we need to make a connection with the database before we doing so:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "my_db");
```

But doing this kind of bugged me because It does not look safe to me. I have to pass a password through the script which has a chance to be exposed to web users.

Is there a safer way of passing the password to the SQL command? How would people in the professional industry deal with this issue?

Comment: exposed to web users? how? it's php, unless in the extremely rare case of a server malfunction (and it serves php without parsing it but as a text file), it's unvisible to the end user. That's the way it's done (well, kindof, those can be served from a config file for example, and just be variables not hardcoded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way.

Usually the password is in a variable/constant and that variable is passed to this command.

If serving this file from a PHP server users on the web will not be able to see the source of this file. Therefore they will never see the password.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I somehow though there will be ways that a hacker can try to download the php code. I think I am overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and safe in normal circumstances. PHP is a server-side language, so all code is evaluated on the server, only the output is sent to the client. So your DB credentials won't ever be transmitted to the user.

Of course, if your server isn't configured right, and it serves the PHP file as plaintext instead of executing it, you will have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The password used in the PHP file is often to an account that only allowed to access the database from localhost. So even if I know the password, I can't access the database over the internet. The connection must me from the same computer, so as long as you protect the access to your servers other services, you should be fine. Also, MySQL's default config is to only listen to connections from localhost.

Comment: Well, that's only partially true. What if I connect to server's DB interface (like Phpmyadmin) and enter username and password I saw in the code? In many hosting providers the PMA directory is easily accessible

Comment: Ture, the combination of a public password and phpmyadmin is not safe

Comment: I see. I never knew that I could play around the settings you mentioned. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

You should be using a 1 way encryption algorithm and then passing the encryption to store in the database. I want to re-enforce 1 way encryption so that even if someone gets hold of it they can't do anything with it. Then when checking to see if the passwords match, you are taking the entered password and encrypting that then matching encryptions. You never ever decrypt it and you are not able to decrypt the password. Basically, after the password is encrypted you just throw it away and never use it again.

Comment: Read the question before answering, OP's talking about the DB connection data, not a login system. btw, I believe you mean "Hashing", not "encryption"